# Elegant way to check if field list is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to check the list of model's fields, like this:

```
[:first_name, :last_name, :city]
```

if all of this fields was filled in.

Ugly code can look like this:

```
# user.rb
def update_profile_completed
    helper = true 
    field_list.each {|field| helper = false if self[field].blank?}
    self.update_attributes(:profile_completed => true) if helper
end
```

I hope this code is good illustration of my problem.

Comment: is this code really in users_controller?  it looks like model code to me, in which case it should just set the value (rather than update_attributes) in a before_save callback

Comment: Sure, it's my mistake, and it is in before_save callback. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def update_profile_completed
  self.update_attributes(:profile_completed => true) unless [:first_name, :last_name, :city].any?{|f| self[:f].blank? }
end
```

Comment: Almost perfect answer, but it should be `if not`, right? Now the expression returns `true` instead of `false` if one of fields is blank.

Comment: Code worked only after I replaced self[:f] with self[f]    ....any?{|f| self[f].blank? }

Answer (score 0):

I used the previous answer for a custom validation then found that it fails on nil.  I switched to

```
[:first_name, :last_name, :city].any?{|f| !self[f].present? }
```

Because it will work on blank or nil.  Note the ! because you are now asking is this 'not present' vs 'is this blank'?